# req.body in nodejs is coming empty:{}?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

This is my angular http request which makes a delete request when deleteEmployee function is called:
This function is called on click of event:

```
$scope.deleteEmployee=function(index){
        $http({

            method:'DELETE',
            url:'/delete',
            data:{

            "ndx":"abc"

            }


        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
```

And this is my server.js file

```
var http=require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));

app.delete('/delete',function(req,res){

   console.log(req.body);

})

app.listen(8888,()=>{
    console.log('Server Started');
})
```

On console.log(req.body) it show empty i.e. {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5:

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

Basically, DELETE requests must not have a body.

Comment: ... which in return means: The resource to be DELETED needs to be identified by the URI itself, i.e. `/delete/ndx/abc`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing syntax :

```
$http.delete('/delete',{"ndx":"abc"});
```